# no se muestra el a href en un menú desplegable en mi pagina html

Tags: html, css

Tengo un menú desplegable en mi página `html` y usé `ccs` para darle diseño, pero no se muestran los enlaces y, si no le pongo texto afuera de la etiqueta a `href`, de plano no aparece el sub menú. Ya he revisado varias veces el código y no encuentro ningún error en esa etiqueta, no sé si el error sea de otra parte del código.

Anexo todo el código que hice.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .mainmenubtn {
      background-color: skyblue;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .mainmenubtn {
      background-color: skyblue;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .mainmenubtn:hover {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-child {
      display: none;
      background-color: skyblue;
      min-width: 200px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-child a {
      color: blue;
      padding: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-child {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<title>Practica 24</title>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="mainmenubtn">Menu Principal 
         </button>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/enespanol/">Sub Menu  1</a>Sub Menu 1 </div>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=es">Sub Menu 2</a>Sub Menu 2</div>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=es-la">Sub Menu  3</a> Sub Menu 3</div>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Sub Menu  4</a>Sub Menu 4</div>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://www.vlive.tv/home/">Sub Menu  5</a> Sub Menu 5</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: El el CSS, en la regla `.dropdown-child a` pones `display:none` que hará que los enlaces no se muestren. Quita eso y los enlaces estarán visibles.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en tu regla `css` para `.dropdown-child a`. Fíjate que solo comentando `/*display: none;*/` los enlaces aparecen y no es necesario poner texto afuera de las etiquetas `<a>`...

Adicionalmente, tienes duplicada la regla para `.mainmenubtn`. Puedes eliminar una de ellas.

```css
.mainmenubtn {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.mainmenubtn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-child {
  display: none;
  background-color: skyblue;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-child a {
  color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*display: none;*/
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Practica 24</title>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="mainmenubtn">Menu Principal</button>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/enespanol/">Sub Menu  1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=es">Sub Menu 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=es-la">Sub Menu  3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Sub Menu  4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a href="https://www.vlive.tv/home/">Sub Menu  5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```